# Стоит ли вообще использовать Rigidbody в играх неплохого качества?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю игру, похожую на Unturned. Столкнулся с многими проблемами, например отталкиванием от коллайдеров (если в них попытатся врезаться), обьект иногда коряво передвигается. Так стоит ли делать свою физику или использовать RigidBody? Если можно, напишите как реализовать гравитацию))

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и содержит слабо связанные друг с другом подвопросы, лучше отдельно задай вопрос про кастомную реализацию гравитации и про поведение сталкивающихся объектов, какое есть и какое желаемо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовать свою физику НЕ стоит. Это слишком сложно.

Если требуется нестандартное поведение в физике (примером может выступить игра Ori and blind forest) то нужно сначала максимально приблизить стандартную физику к нужнопу поведению, а потом пилять просто доп.костыли на физику. **Но физику использовать стандартную.**

Теперь про RigidBody и коллайдеры...

Есть упрощенная обработка коллайдеров а есть более точная(жрет больше ресурсов). Если возникают проблемы, то может быть 2 варианта:

1. Или требуется более точная обработка движком взаимодействия коллайдеров. (может понадобится если какой-то предмет двигается **СЛИШКОМ БЫСТРО**)
2. Или же ты как-то не так реализовал движение конкретного обьекта (например: ты двигаешь персонажа вручную по координатам вместо того, что бы давать ему толчек на его физическую сущность(rigitbody))

В юнити этот пункт есть, но я в упор не помню где именно я его видел и как он называется. Попробуй поискать галочку внутри настроек коллайдера или того же ригитбоди... (Interpolate, Extrapolate)

---

Ну и, собственно, вопрос с собственной реализацией физики лежит в совсем другой плоскости и должен задаваться отдельно....

И, как по мне, то он должен был отпасть при прочтении моего ответа :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я уже конечно разобрался. И вот эти 2 режима обработки коллайдеров - это Interpolate, Extrapolate.